# toFixed method doesn't work on user input but works on other vars in javascript, snippet included

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

I wanted feedback on why toFixed would not work in my JS alert when attached to the user input var usergb. Was a curious thing. I've been encouraged to post and I did not see any other questions out here regarding toFixed issues with user-input vars.

```
var downloadspeed = function () {
        var usergb = prompt("How many gigabytes do you wish to download at 56 kilobits per second?");
        console.log(usergb);
        var hours = (usergb*8388608)/201600;
        console.log(hours);
        var days = (usergb*8388608)/4838400;
        console.log(days);

    //below in the alert is where you will see it, after the first concatenated string, I'd like to type usergb.toFixed(2) but it won't take.


        alert("The number of hours it will take to download a " + usergb + " GB file at 56 kilobits per second is " + hours.toFixed(2) + " hours. This might be a big number. So, in terms of days to download, it'll take "  + days.toFixed(2) + " days to download. This is why we have faster broadband speeds nowadays and why we have video streaming.");

    }
    downloadspeed();
```

The error I get is that it is not a function.

Grazie, Lou

Comment: I just ran that exact code in my browser and it works fine.

Comment: @MikeC - I think, by reading the comment in the code, the issue is that adding `toFixed(2)` to `usergb` in the alert

Comment: @JaromandaX You're right. I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast the input as a number:

```
var usergb = +prompt("How many gigabytes do you wish to download at 56 kilobits per second?");
```

Comment: New thing for me to learn, this means that anytime I do a prompt, as long as I add a + in front of it, it'll accept the input only as a number? Any other quirky plugs that work like that? Thanks!

Comment: @LouDiMe Not exactly. `prompt` always returns a string. The `+` converts the string to a number.

Answer (score 2):

[toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) is a method on a Number ...

[prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) returns a String

try `parseFloat(usergb).toFixed(2)`

Comment: Thanks, makes sense! Another user posted the use of +prompt("blah"); Looks to do the same, any thoughts on difference?

Comment: No thoughts. I like that method better actually

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `toFixed()` on the number:

```
parseFloat(usergb).toFixed(2)
```

The prompt function returns a string, you can not use `toFixed()` on strings, only on numbers.

Comment: Your answer contains the same information as the one posted before it.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the input in the Number type. [Example plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BbO33OlFeSdzgNmwJlVZ?p=info)

```
var downloadspeed = function() {
  var input = prompt("How many gigabytes do you wish to download at 56 kilobits per second?");

  var usergb = new Number(input);
  if(isNaN(usergb))
  {
    alert("You must input a number");
    return;
  }

  console.log(usergb);
  var hours = (usergb * 8388608) / 201600;
  console.log(hours);
  var days = (usergb * 8388608) / 4838400;
  console.log(days);

  //below in the alert is where you will see it, after the first concatenated string, I'd like to type usergb.toFixed(2) but it won't take.


  alert("The number of hours it will take to download a " + usergb + " GB file at 56 kilobits per second is " + hours.toFixed(2) + " hours. This might be a big number. So, in terms of days to download, it'll take " + days.toFixed(2) + " days to download. This is why we have faster broadband speeds nowadays and why we have video streaming.");

}
downloadspeed();
```

Comment: Tried plugging your code but didn't get through, am I missing something from what you plugged?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Did you go to the example plunkr? What browser are you using to test?